# Call asp.net function with out button click from java script directly with out page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to check if the specific value exist in the data base that is working perfect but what i want is

1. I want to call a C# function from JavaScript
2. as now in my code after JavaScript clicks button it response but
   page also refreshes i don't Want page refresh to be happen
3. better way to call C# function with out using button from javascript

   ```
   protected void Check_exam_id(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {         
       string DDSelected_Class = DD_class.SelectedValue;// store it in some variable;
       string DD__Method = DD_Method.SelectedValue;// store it in some variable;

       if (DD__Method == "THEORY")

           {
       using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
       {
           string oString = "Select * from score_master WHERE Class=@DDSelected_Class ";
           MySqlCommand oCmd = new MySqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
           oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DDSelected_Class", DDSelected_Class);

           myConnection.Open();
           using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
           {

               if (oReader == null || !oReader.HasRows)
               {
                   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('No Student Found')", true);


               }
               else
               {
                   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert2", "alert('Exist')", true);

                   myConnection.Close();
               }
           }

       }


       }

   }
   ```

asp button

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" id="Check_examid"  AutoPostback = "false" onclick='Check_exam_id'   style="  display:none;   float: right;    width: 22%;    height: 41px;    text-align: center;    background: #EAEAEA;    border: none;    border-color: #EAEAEA;    margin-top: 2%;" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
```

Javascript

```
    document.getElementById("BodyHolder_Check_examid").click()
```

Comment: Make an _ajax_ call to your method using jquery ajax.

Comment: @RahulSingh am not sure about it if u give me an example that would be more helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can easily do it with *jquery ajax*. For this you will have to define a WebMethod something like this:-

Please include `using System.Web.Services;`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Check_exam_id(string className, string MethodName)
{
    bool examIdExist = false;
    if (DD__Method == "THEORY")
    {
        \\Your logic here
    }
    \\Based on DB operation return value
    examIdExist 
}
```

Finally call it from your client side like this:-

```
$("#Check_examid").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To avoid postback
    //Get these values from dropdwon
    var className = $("#DD_class").val();
    var methodName = $("#DD_Method").val();
    var data = { "className": className , "MethodName": methodName };  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/Check_exam_id",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.d)  //If method returned true.
               alert('Exist');
            else
               alert('No Student Found')
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
    });
});
```

Also, include jquery base library file.

Comment: Thnaks for the reply `[WebMethod]` there is a error it says the name space WebMethod does not exist

Comment: @Shaik - Please include `using System.Web.Services;` in your file.

Comment: I did that is working fine i have a quick question the string `className` if i use it then it is showing me an error

Comment: @Shaik - What error? Are you passing the value from your dropdown as parameters as I have shown?

Comment: Passing From dropdown it is, `Check_exam_id` giving me the error not all code path returns the value string, string,string,string,

Comment: @Shaik - That's what Iam asking when you are having issue? In javascript code or code behind? I have added the code to fetch values from dropdown as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98673/discussion-between-shaik-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: That is giving me the same error i think u should have a look ones if possible

Comment: i am sorry i was out i have shared the screen shot in chat if possible you can have a look

Comment: @shaik - Hey I am also travelling so couldn't see, if possible try to fix otherwise I will be able to check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Make it as a webmethod and call the method from jquery using ajax.
Please find the below link, it contains the example for calling webmethods in asp.net using jquery ajax. 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery ajax method or use UpdatePanels

Create your method Check_exam_id as public static and decorate it as [WebMethod]
And call the javascript function on click event of button as you call any other function.

```
    function DoWork(){
     $.ajax({
          url: 'YourPage.aspx/Check_exam_id',
          data: {}, //blank since you are sending nothing
          dataType:'JSON',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          success:function(){
          alert('Success');
          //Do whatever you want with the HTML
          },
         error:function()
         {
          alert('Error');
            }
         });
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#Check_examid").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To avoid postback
    //Get these values from dropdwon
    var className = $("#DD_class").val();
    var methodName = $("#DD_Method").val();
    var data = { "className": className , "MethodName": methodName };  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/Check_exam_id",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (response) {
            if(response!=null)  //If method returned true.
               alert('Exist');
$("DivId").html(response.d)
            else
               alert('No Student Found')
        },
        error: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
    });
});
```